# Does WebAPI support reading chunked requests by chunk?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api2, owin

### Problem

I am trying to upload some data to a web-service.

I want to upload the data [in chunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), and have the web-service read each chunk in turn. However, what I find in practice is that the web-service will only read a full buffer at a time.

Is there a way to get WebAPI (running self-hosted by Owin ideally, but I can use IIS if necessary) to respect the transfer chunks?

I have verified in Wireshark that my client is sending the data chunked hence why I believe this is a WebAPI issue.

For clarity, streaming data in the response works absolutely fine - my question is about reading chunked data from the request stream.

### Code

The controller looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

public class StreamingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
    {
        var stream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var data = new byte[20];
        int chunkCount = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            // I was hoping that every time I sent a chunk, then 
            // ReadAsync would return, but I find that it will only
            // return when I have sent 20 bytes of data. 
            var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

            if (bytesRead <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{chunkCount++}: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)}");
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

My test client looks like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var url = "http://localhost:6001/streaming/upload";
    var relayRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    relayRequest.Method = "POST";
    relayRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    relayRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
    relayRequest.SendChunked = true;
    relayRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    var stream = relayRequest.GetRequestStream();

    string nextLine;
    int totalBytes = 0;

    // Read a series of lines from the console and transmit them to the server.
    while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((nextLine = Console.ReadLine())))
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nextLine);
        totalBytes += bytes.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(
            "CLIENT: Sending {0} bytes ({1} total)", 
            bytes.Length, 
            totalBytes);
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        stream.Flush();
    }

    var response = relayRequest.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

### Justification

My specific motivation is I am writing a HTTPS tunnel for an RTP client. However, this question would also make sense in the context of an instant-messaging chat application. You wouldn't want a partial chat message to come through, and then have to wait for message 2 to find out the end of message 1...!

Comment: I imagine that this is handled way below the application layer, somewhere in http.sys. Your web-server (probably) hooks the http pipeline provided by http.sys. It's an interesting question that I'll be watching, but my gut feeling is that you'll need to switch to Socket to get this kind of look-in on the request data.

Comment: @spender I don't think so - chunking happens at the HTTP layer, so in theory there is  no reason why the [HttpRequestStream](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_ListenerRequestStream.cs,d40d23a8df78d0e5) class (which is the class WebAPI uses to read the stream) couldn't detect a chunked message boundary and return at that point. A chunked message boundary is just a number (stating how many bytes are to follow), then a CRLF, then the bytes followed by another CRLF.

Comment: If you're using HttpListener, you'd do well to read the following: ["The HTTP Server API decodes chunked messages on the receive side, but does not perform chunked encoding on the send side."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Unless I'm misunderstanding what this means, it's pretty clear that you won't get a look-in because the API that .Net is using does it before it even hits your application.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at the [nowin](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin) project, but you'll probably still have to hack around a bit to get that low in the stack.

Comment: @spender Interesting link, but a bit confusing. If I'm reading this right, it's stating that it will decode a chunked request, but will not encode into chunks in the response. This is the behaviour I am seeing - WebAPI *does* decode the chunks in the request (in the sense that I get the bytes the client has sent, rather than the chunk-encoded bytes). However, I want the request stream to return from read when it reaches a chunk-boundaries. 

Thinking about it, I've just realised that this is too late - the request stream is post-decoding, so doesn't know about the chunking.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying... the de-chunking is happening way-way before it hits your controllers, and usually not even in .Net.

Comment: Yeah - I've just realised that's what you have been gently trying to hammer into my thick skull :) 

Please post as an answer as it's completely correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoding of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` happens a long way away from your controllers. Depending on your host, it may not even happen in the application at all, but be handled by the [`http.sys` pipeline API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that most servers plug into.

For your application to even have a chance of looking into this data, you'll need to move away from IIS/HttpListener and use Sockets instead.

Of interest might be the [Nowin project](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin), that provides all the OWIN features without using HttpListener, instead relying on the Socket async APIs. I don't know much about it, but there ***might*** be hooks to get at the stream before it gets decoded... Seems like a lot of effort though.

Comment: Thanks Spender - for reference, we have to implement it as a HTTPS server (rather than a socket server), as we need to be able to potentially tunnel through corporate firewalls that perform packet inspection, or act as a [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Therefore, we will have to implement our own HTTP server to get the precise behaviour we want, but in our scenario we can probably get away with it for now as we happen to know a-priori that each packet will be 160 bytes. Thanks for the info

Comment: @RB. This looks highly relevant: [OWIN Opaque Stream Extension](http://owin.org/spec/extensions/owin-OpaqueStream-Extension-v0.2.0.htm)